# Exponential of $\bar{z} $

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, exponentiation

I am currently reading the book Complex Variables by Stephen Fisher, there is one paragraph that was written like this: Establishing the following relation, and they write

$$exp(\bar{z})=\overline{exp(z)}$$

the bar on the right is long and span throughout the whole 3 letters and z, what does this mean? And what do they mean by establishing the relation, do I show that they equal each other? There are no further explanations, they just said left for readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bar is the complex conjugate: $\overline{x+iy} = x - iy$.  Your book is saying that for $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then the exponential of z-conjugate is the conjugate of the exponential of z.

Recall Euler's formula: $e^{iy} = \cos(y) + i \sin(y)$.  So, $e^{x+iy} = e^x e^{iy} = e^x(\cos(y) + i \sin(y))$.  Now, consider $e^{x-iy} = e^x(\cos(-y) + i \sin(-y))$.  Sine is an odd function and cosine is an even function, so this is equivalent to $e^x(\cos(y) - i \sin(y))$, which is the complex conjugate of $e^x(\cos(y) + i \sin(y)) = e^{x+iy}$, Q.E.D.

Comment: I understand now, thank you :)

Comment: Do you know what they mean by $\overline{sin(z)}$ then? What does the conjugate sine function look like?